# ODE $y''=f(x)y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been asked how to solve an ODE $y''=f(x)y$, and I am not able to solve it. Could you  enlighten me about this? I would apreciate it so much. If it might be helpful $f$ is a linear function.

Comment: $f$ is a linear function is a very important condition!

Comment: And how can I use that. I know that because $f$ is linear it is integrable but the problem is  $\int y^{-1} dy''$. I do not know how to proceed on that.

Comment: I don’t know myself, but look up “solve second order linear ODE” and I’m certain you’ll get some good ideas

Comment: I have taken a look, and I find lots of stuff on $f$ being constant, but none on non constant coefficients.

Comment: Excuse me, I used the wrong language. You should also specify “inhomogeneous”

Comment: Such equations are in general not solvable. Special cases like the Airy or Mathieu equation can be reduced to reference equations with named solutions, such as Bessel functions. With $f(x)=x^{-2}$ you get an Euler-Cauchy equation. Some insight can be gained from WKB approximations, finding (approximate) basis solutions of the form $y(x)=e^{S(x)}$.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much.

Comment: If $f$ is a polynomial, series techniques could be used. Second order theory is not nearly as nice as first unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, indeed. $f(x)=ax+b$ for certain $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. I will take a look.

Comment: With $f(x)=a x+b$, the solution is Airy functions. Maple gives it as `y(x) = c[1]*AiryAi(1/(-a)^(2/3)*(a*x+b))+c[2]*AiryBi(1/(-a)^(2/3)*(a*x+b))`